# im facing problem with rendering the profile picture in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /profile/1
Invalid block tag on line 14: 'static', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/1
Django Version: 4.1.13
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 14: 'static', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\Users\hrush\anaconda3\envs\djangopython\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 558, in invalid_block_tag
Raised during:  main.views.user_page
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hrush\anaconda3\envs\djangopython\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\hrush\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\eventapp\\core',
 'C:\\Users\\hrush\\anaconda3\\envs\\djangopython\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\hrush\\anaconda3\\envs\\djangopython\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\hrush\\anaconda3\\envs\\djangopython\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\hrush\\anaconda3\\envs\\djangopython',
 'C:\\Users\\hrush\\anaconda3\\envs\\djangopython\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 20 Nov 2023 23:30:41 +0530
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\hrush\OneDrive\Desktop\eventapp\core\templates\profile.html, error at line 14
```

Comment: Please improve this question by providing code (or example code) so we can identify the problem. Also relevant: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the static template tag(s), you do this with:

```
{% load static %}
<!-- rest of the file… -->
```

at the *top* of the file.